# How to update a Youtube channel's name and icon with YouTube API in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

Code:

```
const keywords=["keyword1","keyword2","keyword3"];

function updateChannel() {
  var channels=YouTube.Search.list("snippet",{
    q:keywords[Math.floor(Math.random() * keywords.length)],
    type:"channel"
  })

  var channelpick=channels.items[Math.floor(Math.random() * channels.items.length)]
  var channel=YouTube.Channels.list("snippet,brandingSettings",{'id': "<channel_id>"}).items[0];

  channel.snippet.title=channelpick.snippet.title;
  channel.snippet.thumbnails.default.url=channelpick.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

  YouTube.Channels.update(channel, "snippet") 
}
```

So, what my code does is that it searches for channels under a random keyword and then sets my youtube channel's name and icon as the name and icon of the channel it picked

But an error is occuring when I run `YouTube.Channels.update()` function

Error: `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.channels.update failed with error: 'snippet'`

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Please check if there is any additional description in the error you're getting. By any change do you receive a detail error, like, invalidItemType or badRequest? I checked the documentation and I check that the order is: `YouTube.Channels.update("snippet",channel)`- can you try and let us know?

Comment: That didn't work. I read the documentation and found out that what I'm doing is not possible. Documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update